# htaccess Redirect (Rewrite) if a param NOT exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters, url-rewriting

I try to redirect a page to itself and append a param, but only if the param does **not** exist. It should be:

/page --> /page/?v=12

/page/ --> /page/?v=12

/page/v=10 --> /page/?v=12

/page/?v=12 --> nothing should happen

additionally it should check, if the param is 12 and if not it should also redirect to /page/?v=12

i tried:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)v=(&|$) [NC]
#RewriteRule .* /page/?v=12 [R=302,NC,L]
```

and also

```
#RewriteCond ^(?!page\/\?v=12) [NC]
#RewriteRule .* /page/?v=12 [R=302,NC,L]
```

but either works.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I think i need a redirect as the url should change due to prevent the clients browser from serving a cached page

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there ...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)v=12(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?page/?$ /page/?v=12 [R=302,QSD,L]
```

Comment: its not working as the URL doesn't change... Maybe i need a redirect...

Comment: "Its not working" does not help. You need to be more specific, what does that mean? Do you get an error, did you _really_ check your http server's error log file? What do you see in your browser's network console? Where did you implement that rule? What exact URL did you request?